# В режиме эмуляции IE 8 не подгружаются полифилы с Polyfill.io

Tags: javascript

уважаемые участники сообщества stackoverflow.com!

У меня будет небольшой вопрос к Вам. Кто встречался с подобной проблемой, поделитесь, пожалуйста, как Вы вышли из данной ситуации.

С уважением, Сирота Дмитрий

Итак:
есть простой код, с помощью которого я подключаю к своей странице скрипты, привожу его ниже. (Касательно проета, всё это делается на html-странице, свёрстанной для личного удовольствия). Среди скриптов есть два полифила с ресурса Polyfill.io. Проблема:
в некоторых случаях, например, при использовании эмуляции IE 8 в IE 11 на ОС Windows 7 подгружаются практически пустые файлы без полифилов,. Возможно, ситуация связана с тем, как сервис определяет браузер. Но если в том же режиме эмуляции в адресную строку вставить сформированную на Polyfill.io ссылку, то с большой вероятностью браузер предложит загрузить на компьютер файл со всем необходимым кодом.
Вопрос: это скорее баг Polyfill.io, или я как-то неправильно подключаю скрипты к странице? Если проблема в моём коде, прошу Вас привести свой рабочий. Если проблема в IE, то здесь вряд ли что-то уже поможет;)

Надеюсь на Ваше понимание и Благодарю Вас за уделённое моей проблеме время

P.S. Про Promise-ы знаю, про babel слышал, core.js видел. Интересует именно вопрос с Polyfill.io

P.P.S. Вот код:

```
function appendScript(source, deferFlag) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = source;
    if(deferFlag) {
        script.setAttribute('defer', 'defer');
    }
    try {
        document.body.appendChild(script);
    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.name + ": error in script '" + script.src + "'");
    }
    //
    console.log("script " + script.src + " is added");
    //
    return script;
}
//
function loadScript(src, deferFlag, callback) {
    var script = appendScript(src, deferFlag);
    script.onload = new function() {
        callback(script);
    }
}
//
//Appending scripts to web-page, to body
function loadPage() {
    try {

    loadScript("https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=Object.defineProperties%2CObject.defineProperty", false, function(script) {
        console.log("script " + script.src + " is loaded");
        //
        loadScript("https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.js?features=document.getElementsByClassName%2CElement.prototype.dataset", false, function(script) {
            console.log("script " + script.src + " is loaded");
            //polyfill #1
            appendScript("js/polyfill_isInteger.js", false);
            appendScript("js/script_p1.js", false);
            //polyfill #2
            appendScript("js/polyfill_sayPhrase.js", false);
            appendScript("js/script_p2.js", false);
            //polyfill #3
            loadScript("js/polyfill_Input_month.js", false, function(script) {
                console.log('script "' + script.src + '" is loaded');
                //
                setTimeout(function() {
                    appendScript("js/script_p3.js", true);
                }, 100);
            });
            //tabs
            appendScript("js/script_tabs.js", false);
            //other scripts
            //...
        });
    });

    } catch(error) {
        console.log('Error: ' + error.name + ": " + error.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Пробовали скачать и явно добавить в проект?

Comment: Емуляция IE8 с ней действительно много мороки. Общего лекарства не найдете, ставите проверку на ие, проверку что это 8-мая или 7-мая версия, и методично функциями, или ветками или любым другим образом пишите куски программы, которые по сути будут делать то же самое что библиотечная ф-ция. Может быть существует полифил который прям всё емулирует в случае отсутствия, но врядли.

Comment: @AzizUmarov, так в конечном итоге и сделал

Comment: @nick, Благодарю Вас, может быть дело действительно связано с эмуляцией IE 8. Ещё одно предположение, что при определении браузера сервис видит именно IE 11 и не определяет состояние эмуляции. В любом случае Вы развеяли мои сомнения. С уважением

Comment: IE11 не возможно никак обнаружить в режиме емуляции, он тупо везде говорит что он IE8, и у него не работает ни datalist, ни все новые вещи, которые сейчас есть в скриптах, промисы тоже не будут работать. И в IE11 его не получится переключить.

Comment: @nick, значит я ошибся, буду знать

Comment: Если это действительно "необходимо", то делаете дебаг (он в этом режиме работает). Находите место где запнулся, и допиливаете код, делая его совместимым с ие8. Но проще поставить любой другой браузер корме ие. Сталкивался на работе, в локальной сети по-умолчанию везде стоит галочка "емуляция ие8 в интрасети" т.е. при доступе по локальной сети.

Comment: @nick, нет, в этом нет необходимости, это учебный проект (просто для себя). Ещё раз Благодарю Вас за внимание.
С уважением

Answer (score 0):

`polyfill.io` узнает о вашем браузере по хедеру `user-agent`, скорее всего вы не правильно выставляете  эмуляцию. Надо поставить `user-agent` тоже в `ie8` и тогда `polyfill.io` отдает полифилы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь. Как будет время, проверю.
С уважением